# jquery working in IE only, not on firefox on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on designing an expandable list using jQuery (I'm a newcomer in jQuery). The expandable list is working fine on IE but not on Firefox/Chrome.

On debugging, I found that for firefox/chrome, I'm able to get the `alert('hiiii prepare ORIGINAL')`, but nothing after that. More debugging showed that `function(event)` is not getting executed.

Where is the code going wrong? This isn't the code completely prepared by me but got it from the net and have modified for my purpose.  The credit for original code goes to its author.

I'm using Firefox version 20.0.1 and IE version 9, jQuery version 1.4.2.

js code:

```
function prepareList() {
    alert('hiiii prepare ORIGINAL');
    $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)').click(function (event) {
        alert('inside');
        if(this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
        }
        //return false;
    }).addClass('collapsed').children('ul').hide();

    //Create the button functionality
    $('#expandList').unbind('click').click(function () {
        $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
        $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
    })
    $('#collapseList').unbind('click').click(function () {
        $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
        $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
    })
    // alert('END prepare ORIGINAL');  
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    prepareList();
});
```

CSS:

```
#expList ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#expList p {
    margin:0;
    display:block;
}
#expList p:hover {
    background-color:#121212;
}
#expList li {
    line-height:140%;
    text-indent:0px;
    background-position: 1px 8px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Collapsed state for list element */
#expList .collapsed {
    background-image: url(../../tree/img/collapsed.png);
}
/* Expanded state for list element
/* NOTE: This class must be located UNDER the collapsed one */
#expList .expanded {
    background-image: url(../../tree/img/expanded.png);
}
#expList {
    clear: both;
}
```

**Edit 1:**
I'm posting a fiddle here (thanks to Rocket Hazmat for creating it) http://jsfiddle.net/vrnqA/2/. In this fiddle, when we click on the image, the list expands and collapses. It is happening the same way in IE but not in Firefox. Is it an issue related to the jQuery version? (as I'm novice in jQuery, I'm googling to learn ho to update the version but still, if anyone has ever faced any such problem, please let me know as it would be of great help) 
 **Edit 2:**
 Upgrading jQuery to 1.9.1 didn't help. The problem still persists.
**Edit 3:** 'event' is causing the problem in FireFox it seems. When I placed alert like `alert('event: '+event)` in the js, I was able to see the alert properly in IE but in FirerFox, this alert did not come up. So, it appears that event is not being recognized in FireFox.
**Edit 4:**
Just downloaded firebug with the advise of my friend and it showed error:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined

Any Pointers?
**Edit 5**
Hi Friends, Really thanks for all the support. The issue wasn't with jQuery but with the UI development team who used my code...Had to analyze their UI to spot the error out.... Really Thanks for all the support...

Comment: did the original code work properly?

Comment: Some HTML would also be fine

Comment: Your code works for me in Chrome 27 and Firefox 18: http://jsfiddle.net/vrnqA/1/

Comment: @karthikr ummmm, Actually I didn't get a chance to check it on different browsers but the changes I've made does not touch the functionality much.

Comment: i would check it anyways. There could be a bug in the original code. example: `expandList` might not be a valid DOM element

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's quite cool Rocket. My code is actually having '+' for collapsed list and '-' for expanded list. Is there any way I can post screenshot for you people?

Comment: @Adi: Take a screenshot, edit the post, then click the "upload picture" button (6th button on toolbar).  Better yet, try to make an example like I did, with your real HTML.  As it stands, your code works, so we can't really help without seeing the problem you are.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks and sure, I'll try to post an example here

Comment: @RocketHazmat Not able to post pictures due to low reputation points!! In the fiddle, I can't display my example because I'm using the link to 2 .png files for displaying collapsed and expanded lists.

Comment: @Adi: So, what's the real issue here?  Do the pictures matter?  Can you just post an example without them?  Or just use a placeholder image instead (like http://placehold.it/).

Comment: @RocketHazmat OK, just see your modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vrnqA/. In the fiddle, when we click on image, it's working fine as it does in IE, but in forefox, the collapsed list never appears. It comes as completely expanded one. And that's the main issue. Hope I'm making some sense here!

Comment: @Adi: Did you click the "update" button at the top after editing? That link is still my example :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat OH mY GODDDDDD. I'm sorry. Just did it: http://jsfiddle.net/vrnqA/2/. Please don't mind the delay as I'm on client call simultaneously!

Comment: @Adi: It's ok.  We've all done things like that :)

Comment: Nice joke :) first time i hear that something work with ie and don't work with chrome and firefox not the inverse :)

Comment: @LastBreath lol... It was running in the compatible mode, I discovered this later when I took the UI code from the UI guys... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really thanks for all the support. The issue wasn't with jQuery but with the UI development team who used my code...Had to analyze their UI to spot the error out.... The query searches for li having ul. There is a heavy dependency on the tag formation (please see fiddle in the discussion comments to know more about tag dependency in this jQuery). Analyzed their code and finally fixed it.... Thanks for the support and sorry for informing you all late and if I unintentionally wasted someone's time, I deeply regret. Will be more prompt in future.

**Explanation:**
For forming the tree, UI developer accidentally formed the code like this

```
<ul id="expList">
    <li>test</li>
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
        </ul>    
</ul>
```

Instead of

```
<ul id="expList">
    <li>test
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Just Corrected this!! It appears too naive but the HTML code was actually being generated dynamically with many jsp's giving the input, so it took me time to reach to the solution.
They first told me code was running properly in IE but when I examined it wasn't!! Then they told me that their IE was running in compatibility mode. Yes, in the compatibility mode, IE avoided these errors but did not avoid them in normal mode.. After modification, it is running in all the browsers properly!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether you've got it fixed yet but I've made a few changes to the JSFiddle, here's my version: http://jsfiddle.net/vrnqA/3/

I removed the use of 'event' as this seemed to be causing you the issues.

Here's the modified prepareList function:

```
$('#expList').find('li:has(ul)').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
        $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
}).addClass('collapsed').children('ul').hide();

$('#expandList').click(function() {
    $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded').children().show('medium');
});
$('#collapseList').click(function() {
    $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded').children().hide('medium');
});
```

It's working fine for me in Firefox, Chrome and Safari (all on Mac).

Comment: Hey Joe, really thanks for replying.... Actually it's my fault that I didn't update the co,,unity, was really stuck up with many things, thanks to your mail I remembered I had to reply.... I fixed the issue.. It wasn't with jQuery but with the UI development team who used my code...Had to analyze their UI to spot the error out....

Comment: @Adi you should answer you own question or close it if it's not an issue anymore. Save people wasting their time.

Comment: @LiamI'm very sorry on my part for not closing it as I was very much stuck.... Will make sure this won't happen next time and will not be the cause of time waste of others.